# How can I put my music on dropbox without moving the iTunes folder

Tags: itunes, music, dropbox

I want to copy just my music (not films/tv/etc, so I cant just move the iTunes folder) on to dropbox, so I can listen to it from anywhere for free, but without copying the music as my hard drive space is becoming limited and I don't want to have to recopy everything, everytime I add a new track).

Is there anyway to make Dropbox include the music folder inside the Dropbox folder? If you create a shortcut in the dropbox folder it will just sync the shortcut itself, can I make the shortcut actually be the music folder?

Comment: If you already have a folder in ~/Dropbox/Music/iTunes, then I think you want to use different names to avoid merge conflicts.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The easiest way to this would be to simply create a folder in DropBox and then create a Symbolic Link to your Music only folder in iTunes.

There is a useful article on symlinks available [here](http://hints.macworld.com/article.php?story=2001110610290643). Another one specific to DropBox is available [here](http://forums.dropbox.com/topic.php?id=40992).

In example you could create a symbolic link to a folder named Music in DropBox as follows:

> ln -s ~/Music/iTunes/iTunes\ Media/Music ~/DropBox/Music

Comment: As I understand, Dropbox doesn't follow symlinks?

Comment: @iampearce Actually Dropbox has been designed to follow them: http://forums.dropbox.com/topic.php?id=13431

Comment: I stand corrected. Good call.

Comment: Can you please summarize the link so that all the important information is in your answer? Links have a tendency to degrade and disappear over time, so it is more helpful to put all the information into your answer. Thanks!!

Comment: Dropbox indeed follows the link and uploads all music from /Music without filling up /Dropbox/Music, HOWEVER each synced file was consequently also deleted from /Music. Fortunately all music was successfully uploaded and I could retrieve it. Not a fail proof method.

Answer (score 1):

Why not physically move the folder in Finder into your dropbox (so instead of Music > iTunes Music you have Dropbox > iTunes Music) and then change the directory of your library (through iTunes > Preferences) to be in the right place?

No duplicates, music synced, all happy?

Comment: Because if I change the directory of the library then dropbox will sync TV and Movies which will put me over the 2GB dropbox limit.

Comment: In which case, the symlink option Diago posted would be your best solution.

Comment: You could use Dropbox's Selective Sync feature to exclude the TV and Movies folders from being uploaded by Dropbox https://www.dropbox.com/en/help/175

Comment: You may want a duplicate copy on your Mac incase your Dropbox is on an external SSD, but want to listen to music or watch videos on the go